# Compatibility about CSS ::first-letter and UTF-8 mb4

Tags: css, html, unicode, utf-8, emoji

So, here's my problem: I'm creating a website where I've some posts. In those posts, I put a "::first-letter" highlighting to make it bigger, and it works perfectly.

But, when I'm going to load a post with first letter as a Unicode Emoticon that is a UTF-8 mb4 (2 Unicode Chars), it fails, by trying to load the single char as 2 separated, so the result is something strange.

This is a screenshot:

[image: Error with unicode and ::first-letter]

How can you see, there's a bigger letter and one smaller that are unknown, and then the same emoticon visible, because I created a post with the same emoticons wrote down 2 times.

```css
.first_letter_post::first-letter {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="first_letter_post">foobar</p>
```

This is the character: , and I'm using Google Chrome.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Can you also post a sample of the character itself, and what browser this is in? Are you sure it's an issue of CSS styling and not the character output itself?

Comment: I added the character and the browser used. I'm sure about it because if I add a lot of more of that icon after the first one it show without any problem.

Comment: I've converted this to a live example for you. Indeed, it breaks in Chrome. Works fine in Safari.

Comment: Hahaha, Chrome. You and your broken emoji support once again.

Comment: Thanks for the Live example. Do you have any idea?

Comment: On Firefox, ::first-letter does not match the emoji. On IE and Microsoft Edge, ::first-letter *does* match the emoji. I haven't gone through the css-text and css-pseudo-4 specs in depth, but based on what I know Firefox's behavior is conformant to spec, since an emoji technically isn't a letter according to the Unicode spec.

Comment: I believe there was an explicit remark in the CSS specs somewhere that `::first-letter` doesn't necessary succeed for non-letters. That said, I like IE's result best.

Comment: (`utf8mb4` applies only to MySQL; removing from tags.)

Comment: @Rick James: :O You have 22,222 rep!

Comment: @BoltClock -- sorta like the odometer rolling over!

Comment: @RickJames Thanks, added only to let people understand better what type of emoticon give the problem.

Comment: The "black diamond" could be another issue... See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has a long know history of problems with unicode [[bug]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=597510). This issues is a combination of those problems:

1. Failing to correctly recognize symbols consisting of more than 3 bytes.
2. Styling symbols regardless of being a letter unit

This results in Chrome tearing a single symbol apart.

IE is correctly recognizing unicode symbols consisting of multiple codepoints and applies the styling regardless of the spec stating that `::first-letter` should be applied to [typographic letter units](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#first-letter-pseudo) only.

Firefox behaves very strict to the spec, not applying styles to non-letter units. I could not determine whether the Alphanumeric Supplement Space should be treated as [letter as well](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#character-properties), but Firefox is not treating them as such.

This means, that you should refrain from using `::first-letter` when you are heavily relying on it and know that those characters might occur.

A possible solution I could think of, is manually detecting the first character via javascript and wrapping it in a tag and then apply the styles. My solution is a bit messy due to the hard coded hex value, but it might be sufficient.

```js
// manually wrapping the "first character"
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"),function(el){wrapFirstChar(el)});

function wrapFirstChar(div){
  let content = div.innerHTML,chars=content.charCodeAt(0) >= 55349?2:1;
  div.innerHTML = "<span>"+content.substring(0,chars)+"</span>"+content.substring(chars);
}

// this is what javascript sees at the first two positions of the string
//Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("p"),(e)=>console.log(e.innerHTML.charCodeAt(0)+"+"+e.innerHTML.charCodeAt(1)));
```

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:red;
}
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue;
}
p{
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<h2>using ::first-letter</h2>
<p> 4 bytes symbol</p>
<p> Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement 1F170</p>
<p> Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols 1D7B9</p>
<p> Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols 1EE00</p>
<p>a normal character (1 byte)</p>

<h2>manually replaced</h2>
<div> 4 bytes symbol</div>
<div> Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement 1F170</div>
<div> Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols 1D7B9</div>
<div> Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols 1EE00</div>
<div>a normal character (1 byte)</div>
```

Comment: Firefox is not "failing" here - it's conforming to spec. Emoji are neither considered typographic letter units by css-text's definition, nor punctuation (as Unicode classifies them as Symbols) and therefore ::first-letter will not match *anything* if the first formatted line begins with an emoji. I suspect by "correctly" you meant "as I would expect" (in a similar vein to Mr Lister's comment on the question), since IE's behavior of treating emoji as typographic letter units is *incorrect*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I corrected/clarified my answer accordingly.